# RepoForge used across many StackOverflow docs is down, What is the alternative?

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, git

I'm trying to download git. I could build from source except I have no source packages. 
I tried `yum install git` but that couldn't find it. 
I tried downloading the git rpm directly from Repoforge , but was unsuccessful:

```
 wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/git/git-1.7.10.4-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
```

I think repoforge is down. It just hangs, no 404, no error, no nothing. 
What is the alternative for downloading a git.rpm for CENTOS 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

[EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) may be what you seek.

According to the `FAQ` from the above site the `EPEL repo` can be installed using:

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm'
```

According to the [CentOS Wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge),

> "RPMForge/RepoForge is a dead project. It is not maintained. DO NOT USE."

Even if `Repoforge` was still alive, the `git rpm` you are attempting to install is for `CentOS 6` not `CentOS 5`.

Comment: yeah, I noticed. I found a way to download individual rpms , but dependency purgatory awaits if I do that: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/29419633/dir/redhat_el_5/com/git-1.7.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm.html  I tried EPEL , but I can't get it enabled in yum for some reason... is there a special command other than `yum install --enablerepo=epel.repo`

Comment: The command to enable EPEL is provided above, did you actually read the reply? This is also documented at https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F